# How sorted is an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Suppose we have an array of integers with length of `n`. We need a function like `f(arr, n)` which returns a number between `-100%` and `+100%`. The closer the result is to `+100%`, the more array is in ascending order; and the closer the result is to `-100%`, the more array is in descending order. If array is completely in a random order, the result should be close to `0%`.

This is my implementation so far:

```cpp
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

int f(int arr[], int n) {
    int p = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int a = arr[i];
        int b = arr[i + 1];

        if (a != b) {
            bool asc_check = a < b;
            bool desc_check = a > b;

            if (asc_check && !desc_check)
                p++;

            else if (!asc_check && desc_check)
                p--;
        }
    }

    return map(p, -(n - 1), n - 1, -100, 100);
}
```

I doubt my code is accurate. Please help me to write the correct implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the metric that you use? It is not obvious [how to measure "sortedness"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11836).

Comment: Why do you doubt your code? Have you tried out example inputs and measured if what they return is what you think they should?

Comment: @jdehesa I actually want to make a custom sorting algorithm that depends on given array's sortedness, uses either Insertion Sort (if it is more in ascending order) or any other sorting algorithm which it's best case scenario is the array being in descending order.

Comment: @Aziuth I only wonder if I could do better?!

Comment: If you have code you believe works and you want it to work better, consider asking over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Note that I have linked to the How to Ask help pages. Make sure you are familiar with their requirements and adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that `if ...` code is more complicated than it needs to be. Once you've determined that `a != b`, either `a < b` or `a > b`; you don't have to test both conditions. So: `if (a != b) { if (a < b) p++; else p-- }`. Personally, I'd write it with more symmetry: `if (a == b) ; else if (a < b) p++; else p--;` but some folks don't like that style.

Comment: @MahdiBeitari Again define _sortedness_ please. Do you mean _entropy_?

Comment: @MahdiBeitari By what measure? Let me elaborate: there should be a goal for you to reach, a problem to solve. Take that and then define a measure on the quality of your algorithm based on the needs of the problem. Without this, you are trying to solve a problem that you can't even name. To give you an example for a measure: "Given a collection of unsorted vectors with uniformly created sorting orders, the in-between states in iterations of a given sorting algorithm should when evaluated under your algorithm produce a approximately linear graph".

Comment: @PeteBecker yes; you are right. Thanks for little hint!

Comment: @MahdiBeitari Have you considered simply using [std::is_sorted_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until), and then take the ratio of the total number of elements and the return value of `is_sorted_until`?

Answer (score 0):

could use the sort class that the STL library provides in c ++